# Empty String Array: Is there a difference between [] and [""]?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, is-empty

In Swift for iOS:
Empty String Array: Is there a difference between [] and [""] ?

```
let arrA: [String] = []
let arrB: [String] = [""]
```

What is the difference between arrA and arrB ?

Which one is the "better" way to initialize a String-Array in Swift ?

Comment: Try fetching the length between the 2, and see if there is a difference.

Comment: yes, there is; one of them has _zero_ item, the other one has _one_ item; which is which? well... it is the better if that is up to you to figure out.

Comment: For an empty array I'd prefer this – more distinct – syntax `let arrC = [String]()`

Answer (score 3):

`arrA` is an empty array (an array with zero elements).

```
let aCnt = arrA.count // aCnt = 0
```

`arrB` is an array that contains *one* element, namely an empty `String` at index `0`.

```
let bCnt = arrB.count // bCnt = 1
```

The best way to initialize an array, depends on what you are going to use the array for. Unless you need an array with a single empty string element, I would use the `arrA` approach.

Comment: Thank you, Klaus, for the ultra-quick answers! I added one more question: `Which one is the "better" way to initialize a String-Array in Swift ?` (i.e. what is the best practice in Swift) ?

Comment: @Cristik give me a break... the question was edited after my initial answer.

Comment: @Cristik: The second part of the question was added after Klaus' ultra-quick response....!

Comment: @iKK unless you _want_ your array to contain the empty string for some reason, you want to initialize it as `[]`. That is the _empty_ array, and a sensible default.

Answer (score 1):

`arrA`: It's an empty Array

`arrB`: It's an array with one String with no characters.

> Which one is the "better" way to initialize a String-Array in Swift ?

The first one (`ArrA`). With this way you are initializing a empty array, and thats what you want in most cases.

Comment: Cristik: The second part of the question was added after Enrique's ultra-quick response....!

Comment: The first one (`ArrA`). With this way you are creating a empty array, and thats what you want in most cases.